# Remove letters from string in Python

Tags: python, string, character

I need to define a function that takes two arguments `(s1, s2)`. This function should remove the letters of `s2` that are in `s1`. For example removing the letters `"motor"` from `"motorcycle"` should result in `"cycle"`. I know how to do it for a specific letter of one string, but not from two strings.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be an interesting problem, what's your approach on this BTW ?

Comment: I was thinking of rebuilding the string?

Comment: it should result in `"rcycle"` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `s2.replace(s1, '')`

```
>>> a = 'motor'
>>> a.replace('moto', '')
'r'
```

Strings in Python are immutable, so to change the vale of a do -

```
>>> a =a.replace('moto', '')
```

Specifically for your problem

```
def replace_letters(x,y):
   return x.replace(y,'')
```

Comment: it still displays `motorcycle`

Comment: `def remove_letters(s1, s2):
 s2.replace(s1, '')
 
 return s2`

Comment: You need to reassign s2 the new value. I have updated my answer with the relevant code.

Comment: @Bensal Utkarash is it something like this:

`def remove_letters(str1, str2):`
       `str2.replace(str1, '')`
       `a = a.replace('moto', '')`
       `b = b.replace('','motorcycle')`
       `return (str2)`

Comment: What are the variables a and b doing here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95067/discussion-between-trex00-and-bansal-utkarsh).

Comment: Added the function in the answer. Works now?